# Easiest Way to Access Neo4J from Java

Tags: jdbc, neo4j

I want to access a Neo4j DB with Java and wanted to know what the preferred way to do this is. I just want to write a quite simple data structure to the DB.

http://neo4j.com/developer/java/ gives following options:

- JDBC
- Hibernate OGM
- Spring Data
- Rest API via Unmanaged Extensions

I looked into accessing Neo4J with JDBC and Hibernate OGM. It seems that its not worth it to use for me. JDBC gives me some trouble. So should i go with the REST way or try to fix my JDBC problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JDBC driver is really a wrapper around the REST interface (as of neo4j 2.3). There is a [example application](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-jdbc) how to use it. Should suffice for very simple use.

Then there is [neo4j-ogm](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm) (different from Hibernate OGM) - this is an object graph mapping library, similar to hibernate in ORM world. This has minimal external dependencies and is very easy to use - ideal for cases where you want to map couple of objects into graph.

Then there is the Spring Data Neo4j project, which since version 4 uses neo4j-ogm for mapping, but adds other Spring data features, like repositories, derived finder queries, transactions ...